# How to get data from scope by rootscope

Tags: angularjs

I got an `app.run` where i get my data from an webintent. In the app.run i'm not allowed to use `$scope` so i use `$rootscope`.Now my `$scope` got `$scope.sendURL(Object)` and I want to make this call inside my `app.run`.

I searched a lot on stackoverflow and google and I came acros `$broadcast` and `$emit`. But i can't figure out if that is right thing to do. Does somebody know what i should try?

edit:
I need to call the `$scope.sendURL` inside `app.run` and i have no idea how to do it. I searched on stackoverflow and came acros `$broadcast` and `$emit`but i'm not use if i need to use them.

Comment: Briefly explain your requirement. It's unclear here.

Comment: Where do you define `$scope.sendUrl`? In a controller?

Comment: @akki_java updated it

Comment: You can make factory and call that from any controller regardless of scope.

Comment: @tasseKATT Yes i got .controller('abc',abc); then i inject ['$scope','$http',etc] than i have a function abc('$scope','$http',etc) inside this function i got the function $scope.sendUrl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the logic into a factory and use the factory in `run` and in your controller:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.run(function (myFactory) {

  var data = {};

  myFactory.sendURL(data);
});

app.controller('MyController', function ($scope, myFactory) {

  $scope.sendURL = myFactory.sendURL;
});

app.factory('myFactory', function ($http) {

  return { sendURL : sendURL };

  function sendURL(data) {

    // Put the logic here
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you , i will try this solution!